# ¿Como poner el height automatico de un Iframe dependiendo del src?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

como están? Tengo una consulta yo tengo un **iframe** como el que muestro mas abajo. 
El **src** de ese iframe cambia de acuerdo a una botonera, es decir, tengo un par de botones que al tocarlo cambian el **src**. El **Iframe** siempre muestra gráficos estadísticos, mi problema es la altura, porque cuando muestro un **Iframe** con altura de mas de **1200**(es la altura del iframe actual) no entra en ese tamaño y por ende se genera el **scroll** dentro del **iframe** y quisiera que eso no pase.

Este es mi código **HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="contenedor">
       <h2> Claro Smart </h2>
        <iframe id="frame" class="frame" src="http://stableaufront01/views/embed" frameborder="0" width="1200" height="1200" scrolling="no">
      </iframe>
   </div>   
</div>
```

Pongo mi código **css** de las clases que rodean al **iframe**:

```
.wrapper {
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
}

.contenedor,
.contenedor-img
{
    width: 98%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){
    .contenedor,
    .contenedor-img{
        width: 95%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .contenedor,
    .contenedor-img{
        width: 90%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px){
    .contenedor{
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 1100px;
    }

    .contenedor-img{
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 1600px;
    }
}

audio,
canvas,
iframe,
img,
svg,
video {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.frame{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Lo que intenté hasta el momento fue todas las posibles soluciones que dan en este otro stack(ingles):
[Make iframe automatically adjust height according to the contents without using scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

Pero no me funcionó ninguna de las respuestas. Algo que cabe aclarar en a consola me sale lo siguiente:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://127.0.0.1:5500" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at resizeIframe (http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html:173:56)
>       at HTMLIFrameElement.onload (http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html:170:85)

También intenté usar la librería de este link:
[iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)
Que lo obtuve desde este otro stack:
[Resize Cross Domain Iframe Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086722/resize-cross-domain-iframe-height)

Pero en este ultimo caso, no puedo afirmar que me dio error porque no me funcionó pero quizás sea que lo utilicé mal.

En fin, ¿ Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal con las soluciones? **¿ O si conoce alguna solución a mi problema?** Quiero que cuando se cambie el src, el height del iframe se ajuste a lo que traiga el iframe(se agrande o achique).

Comment: Es peligroso para el rendimiento quitarle el scroll a un elemento, porque si el elemento es pesado (como un iframe), que resulta bastante pesado en si mismo, afectara el rendimiento en un 50% si se deja el scroll y quien sabe cuanto caera el rendimiento al no tener scroll, si bien es cierto que al no tener scroll hay un limite de renderizado de objetos que esta delimitado por lo visible en pantalla, esto hará que el iframe consuma posiblemente el doble, afectando el rendimiento en un 100%, es decir, podrias estar consumiendo casi el doble de recursos solo por quitarle el scroll a un iframe.

Comment: Bueno... eso asumiendo que el height sea dinamico dependiendo del src que es lo que deseas... porque solo quitarle el scroll no afectaria el rendimiento, pero hacer visible todo el iframe de acuerdo al alto de la pantalla es lo que si afectaria el rendimiento.

Comment: @Riven entendido! Pero de igual forma me gustaría, si se puede, hacer automático el height. Seguí investigando, sin conseguir los resultados pero por lo que leí no se puede realizar lo que quiero. Porque no pertenece a mi dominio y porque el sitio es "privado". Tengo otra posible solución, aunque no es la que quiero. La solución consiste en mandar por parámetro la altura a la función donde cargo el iframe. No es la mejor solución, pero de momento sirve.

Comment: @Riven por cierto, muchas gracias por responder mi pregunta y por compartir tu conocimiento! Y consejos!

Answer (score 0):

prueba usando esta function en el onload de tu iframe. Suerte

```
 function resizeIframe(obj) {
      obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';               
 }
```

en el html deberia quedarte asi

```
<iframe id="frame" class="frame" src="http://stableaufront01/views/embed" frameborder="0" width="1200" height="1200" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)">
    </iframe>
```